# Mixing System.Text.Json and Newtonsoft.Json with Swagger

Tags: c#, asp.net, json.net, swagger, system.text.json

One of my company's applications import packages that contain models that become responses from our API

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
public class Foo 
{
    [JsonProperty("bar"]
    public string Bar { get; set;} 
}
```

We have for our own models migrated to `System.Text.Json`, which uses `[JsonPropertyName("foobaz")]`

Swagger picks up the correct formatting for our own models automatically, but not for the imported packages.

If we add `AddSwaggerGenNewtonsoftSupport` in program.cs, it picks it up for the imported models, but not for our models.

Is there any way to tell swagger to handle both?

Answer (score 1):

use both attributes

```
    [JsonProperty("bar"]
    [JsonPropertyName("foobaz")]
    public string Bar { get; set;}
```